# Selector is not recognized with in jQuery Ajax success function in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I have a very serious problem with a template I have to fix : boosterius for Worpress.
I need to optimize it and make it work with IE …
So, I have decided to load the page with ajax because there is a lot of picture (at the first place, all pages was loaded in the same page :/).
All work perfectly in Firefox, but in IE it's the hell.

My problem at this time, is that IE don't want recognize some ajax loaded elements.

```
var container = _.curr.find('.the-content');
var page = container.parents('li');
$.post(
url, {
    ajaxloaded: '1',
    pageloaded: _.curr.attr('id')
},

function (data) {
    var newcurr = $(data).find('#' + _.curr.attr('id'));
    var newcontainer = $(newcurr).find('.the-content');
    container.html(newcontainer.html());
    var scrollbar_new = container.find('.scrollbar1')[0];
    console.log('nScroll:' + $(container).find('.scrollbar1').length);
    if ($(data).find('.scrollbar1').length > 0) {
        $(data).find('.scrollbar1').each(function (i) {
            console.log('scrollid:' + $(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).tinyscrollbar({
                sizethumb: 134
            });
        });
    }
});
```

IE return an error on `$(this).tinyscrollbar({ sizethumb: 134 });` like `$(this)` couldn't accept the tinyscrollbar function :/ (but it work for the element loaded at the fisrt page load).
I tried with the exact id `($('#exactID'))` for the same result…

Thanks for your help ! :)

**Edit : So it seems that the problem is caused by the lost of the plug-ins in the `$(window).load()` function, but they are still there in the `$(document).ready();`**

Comment: start by pressing F12 in ie to open the console if you haven't already so that the console.log() won't fail, then do `console.log($.type($.fn.tinyscrollbar))` to make sure the plugin is loaded.

Comment: Ok, nice one, it return "undefined", but it is on a $(window).onload function, how could it be possible ? (Firefox return "function")

Comment: Ok, I have tested the snippet in an `$(document).ready` function and he returns "function". What's the problem ? `ready` should be fired after `onload`, why the function is defined in `ready` and not in `onload` ? oO

Comment: That depends on where the code is located on the page. Could you possibly be including jquery.js in two places?

Comment: Yes there is 2 jquery.js loaded, could it be a problem (I know it's not good, and I'm working on it) ?

Comment: Yeah, that could definitely cause problems, when you load in one jQuery.js over another, the previous one is overridden, resulting in lost plugins.

Comment: Good to know
I have delete one, the problem is still there :/

Comment: can you show the <script> tag for tinyscrollbar?

Comment: what do you mean by "showing the <script> tag" ? In fact there is a problem with tinyscrollbar, but with fancybox and easing too :/

Comment: IE doesn't interpret type="application/javascript" as javascript, just wanted to make sure that wasn't what was happening.

Comment: Ok, no, it's not that, Wordpress generates the tags so it's fine.
Note that the `console.log` returns "function" in the DOM.ready, so the function is well loaded but returns "undefined" in the window onload

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank for your help, I've learn some trick.
So, I've found the solution : desactivate a module.
The module which cause the trouble :

Nom :                       **smartdownloader Class**

Éditeur :                   Terra Firma Internet Consulting LTD

Type :                      Objet Application d’assistance du navigateur

Version :                   1.0.0.1

Date du fichier :

Date du dernier accès :     ‎Aujourd’hui ‎19 ‎janvier ‎2013, ‏‎il y a 6 minutes

ID de classe :              {F1AF26F8-1828-4279-ABCE-074EF3235BD7}

Utilisations :              23

Nombre de blocages :        9

Fichier :                   smarterdownloader.dll

Dossier :                   C:\Program Files (x86)\ **SockshareDownloader**